# Can't Access wp-admin after hosting in new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I know that question asked many times before and I tried many of them but cant find solution.
this is my site url
http://www.primeproductionltd.com (most of things work fine)
http://www.primeproductionltd.com/wp-admin/

previousy It is on server - http://applanche.com/prime-production/wp-admin/

in have added in my wp.config

```
define('WP_HOME','primeproductionltd.com/'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','primeproductionltd.com/')
```

My Htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

There is some cookie and rediret error shown.

Comment: What happens when you try to access `wp-admin`? The `.htaccess` file shouldn't cause any issues as it's not affected by the rewrite rules.

Comment: It says

    www.primeproductionltd.com redirected you too many times.
    Try clearing your cookies.
    ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I tried with wp-login.php but result is same.

Link is given above on question

Comment: Have you set the URLs in the `wp-config` constants to the exact address you're wanting to use? I know you've changed them to `example.com` but they must be the exact domain you're wanting to use.

Comment: Yes It is same 

define('WP_HOME','http://www.primeproductionltd.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.primeproductionltd.com/');

Comment: You need to include the `http://www` as well for each.

Comment: Use `http://primeproductionltd.com` (no trailing slash).

Comment: I add `http://www` but result is still same

Comment: @stealthyninja  Still same  ..